# Find disjoint sets of vertexes in a Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I want to find a simple method to generate sets of disjoint parts in a Graph. In other words, in the following Graph, I want to get two sets of {A, B, C, D} and {E, F}.
[image: Sample Disjoint Graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any graph traversal algorithm ([BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) and [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) are the most common).

Whenever the algorithm is "stuck" (there is no more nodes to traverse), you have finished finding one component, mark it, and choose a random vertex that was not traversed yet to find the next component.